# `rgl`-Output in bookdown-html does not rotate properly

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, rgl, bookdown

Using `{rgl}` output within single-file bookdown-documents works perfectly in the following minimal example:

````
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

Here's the figure:

```{r webgl=TRUE}
library(knitr)
library(rgl)
knit_hooks$set(webgl = hook_webgl)

with(iris, plot3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                  type="s", col=as.numeric(Species)))
```
````

However, when using the same code in the [official minimal-example](https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown-demo), rotating does not work properly...

Comment: Don't use `webgl=TRUE` and `hook_webgl`, use a call to `rglwidget()`.

Comment: Thank's - but that does not solve the problem. Horizontally rotation is still not working properly...

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Same problem here: it conflicts with the section navigation of Bookdown